# change panel from second class to first class

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jbutton

i am doing my exercise about insert data with login admin, student and teacher. but i got stack at logout.

## First Class Test5.java

```
  public class Test5 extends JFrame implements ActionListener , ItemListener {
  public Container contentPane = this.getContentPane();
    public Test5(){
    CardLayout card = new CardLayout();
    setLayout(card);
    setSize(1366,768);
    setTitle("Student Data Editor");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(true);
    try{
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/kampus", "root", "abc");
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
    }catch(Exception e){
    }
    dosen dos = new dosen();
    siswa sis = new siswa();
    contentPane.add("main", main);
    contentPane.add("student", sis.panel_siswa);
    contentPane.add("dosen", dos.panel_dosen);
    main = new JPanel();   //first Panel
    main.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    label_main = new JLabel("ID");
    label_main2 = new JLabel("Password");
    tf_main = new JTextField(15);
    tf_main2 = new JPasswordField(15);
    login = new JButton("LOGIN");
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("LOGIN")){
            card.show(contentPane, "dosen");
        }
    }
}
```

### Second Class dosen.java

```
public class dosen implements ActionListener{
JPanel panel_dosen;
    public dosen(){
    panel_dosen = new JPanel(); //second panel
    panel_dosen.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    panel_dosen.add(panel_combo, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel_dosen.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel_dosen.add(panel_input, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
          if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Logout")){ //it didnt work at all and dont have any error
             Test5 tes = new Test5();
             tes.add(tes.main);
             tes.remove(panel_dosen);
             tes.tf_main.setText("");
             tes.tf_main2.setText("");
          }
   }
}
```

### Problem

First Panel
[image]

Second Panel
[image]

### Question

how to make second panel removed and add first panel add jframe ?

Answer (score 1):

> how to make second panel removed and add first panel add jframe ?

Use a `CardLayout`. The `CardLayout` was specifically designed to allow the swapping of panels in the same space.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) for more information and working examples.

Comment: am i need to make panel for jframe ?

Comment: @KiraKatou  `am i need to make panel for jframe ?` no idea what you are asking. Read the tutorial!!! Download the code and modify the working code to meet your requirement. If there is something about the tutorial code you don't understand then ask a specific question. But DON'T ask a question when you haven't even tried the code. You learn by trying.

Comment: i'll try to understand that first and make a new file about this one :D

Comment: can u check my code ? i already update it, but it didnt work "NullPointerException"

Comment: Well, fix the NPE. That is the most common Exception you will get while programming. The stack trace will tell you the line causing the problem. Then determine which variable is null and fix the problem. We are not here to do basic debugging for you. You need to develop your own problem solving skills. You were given a link to the Swing tutorial which contains a working example. I suggest you start with the working examples and modify that code. Your program will be better structured and easier to maintain and debug.

Answer (score 1):

This is a use case for [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html). Make CardLayout your JFrame's layout manager instead of BorderLayout